# Spring ContractDsl import one field in resources and java class

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have base class in contractTest/java/.. and contracts in contractTest/resources/..
I have ContractFields.java:

```
public class ContractFields {
    public static final String betId = "2140";
}
```

And use betId in contract:

```
...
body (betId: ContractFields.betId)
```

I get error when run contractTest task:

```
unable to resolve class ...ContractFields
```

How i can i do create field in somewhere and import it in groovy contracts and java base class?